Create Blob and Storage Account under azurerm_monitor_diagnostic_setting using TF
I am trying to create blob storage under Storage account which is created fine, but when i am trying to create diagnostic setting for same. It shows storage account as "disabled" and blob container as "Enabled. I want both of these two be enabled. Please suggest.
resource "azurerm_monitor_diagnostic_setting" "core-diagnostic" {
  name                       = "readwrite${random_string.random.result}"
  target_resource_id         = "${azurerm_storage_account.core.id}/blobServices/default/"
  log_analytics_workspace_id = azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.core.id

  log {
    category = "StorageRead"
    enabled  = true
  }

  log {
    category = "StorageWrite"
    enabled  = true
  }

  metric {
    category = "Transaction"
    enabled  = true
    retention_policy {
      days    = 5
      enabled = true
    }
  }
}

